# ¿Por qué mi tipo de dato double no hace la operacion correcta?

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

El tipo double no hace correctamente la operación, al ingresar el monto de 2500 suma correctamente los 50 pero después 2550*0.02 es 51 y vuelve simplemente a sumar 50 y así con los posteriores 11 meses restantes

```
*/Objetivo: Obtener la cantidad de dinero que la persona obtendrá al cabo 
de un tiempo si el banco le otorga un 2% de interes mensual y la ganancia 
de cada mes es reinvertida
/*
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Problema1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      //Declaracion de variables
      double dinero=0, im=0 ,ganancia=0; //im es interes mensual
      String dato="";
      dato=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad que desea invertir");
      dinero=Double.parseDouble(dato);
      System.out.println("usted esta ganando");
      for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
      {
         im=(dinero*0.02);
         ganancia=(dinero+im*i);
         System.out.println(ganancia);         
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo creo que la multiplicacion que estas haciendo en el **ganancia=(dinero+im*i);**
estaria por demas el i ya que eso te esta generando un calculo mal. ese es mi primer punto 
el segundo punto es que la actualizacion del IM no se esta dando por ende siempre sera el mismo valor Im.
Quitando esos errores tu problema se solucionaria.
Aqui te dejo el codigo correcto al problema.

```
package problema01;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
*
* @author Frank
*/
 public class Problema01 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
     //Declaracion de variables
  double dinero=0, im=0 ,ganancia=0; //im es interes mensual
  String dato="";
  dato=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad que desea invertir");
  dinero=Double.parseDouble(dato);
  System.out.println("usted esta ganando");
  for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
  {
     im=(dinero*0.02);
//   System.out.println(im);
     ganancia=(dinero+im);
    dinero=ganancia;

     System.out.println(ganancia);         
  }
}
```

}